# Can roll be controlled through elevators in a fixed-wing aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, flight-controls

In fixed-wing aircraft, roll is typically controlled through ailerons.

But I am wondering if roll could also be controlled through split, independently controllable left/right elevators?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. 
Fighter jets with split elevators can command a roll in the way you describe, [see this answer for more info.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/47708/do-fighter-jets-use-elevators-as-ailerons)

For an aircraft like a [delta wing (tail-less)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_wing) that lacks a [traditional empennage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empennage) these [control surfaces are combined into an elevon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevon) to produce a mix use elevator aileron.

The [Concorde is a classic implementation](https://www.heritageconcorde.com/concorde-elevons-and-rudder) of this design. [Flying wings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_wing) like the [B-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_Grumman_B-2_Spirit) also use this design.